# Как разобраться с версиями библиотек в .NET Standard?

Tags: .net, .net-standard

Создаю проект на .NET Framevork v 4.6.1.

К нему создаю библиотеку ядра .NET Standard. При создании библиотеки предлагалось выбрать версию фреймворка. В итоге создался проект определенной версии Standard. Но при запуске оказалось, что не совпадает версия сборки System.Net.Http. Мне пришлось понизить версию .NET Standard (ну не то что бы пришлось. Я погуглил, понизил и это помогло).

Теперь вот установил к этой библиотеке Nuget пакет Newtonsoft.Json и при запуске ловлю исключение, что данная сборка версии 10.0.0 не найдена. WTF??? Почему ищется именно такая версия, если установлена версия 10.0.3? Я хотел сделать даунгрейд, но версии 10.0.0 вообще нет. Есть 10.0.1 (она не подходит) и ниже уже 9.

Помогите разобраться со всеми этими зависимостями и версиями. Общий смысл бы хоть уловить.

**UPD:**

Я ведь в коде пишу что то типа

```
var serializer = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonSerializer.Create();
```

Я нигде не указываю, какую версию библиотеки мне использовать. Но требуется почему то конкретная версия. А если требуется конкретная версия, то почему установилась последняя, а не требуемая?

**UPD2:**

Перевел проект на версию фреймворка 4.7, повысил версию .net Standard, появились проблемы с версией сборки System.Runtime. Я ваще запутался короче

**UPD3:**

В папке, куда собирается проект, нет библиотеки Newtonsoft.Json.dll. Возможно, дело в этом. Почему библиотека не подтянулась? Как быть?

Comment: Сам вчера на похожие вилы наступил. Майки совсем недавно зарилизили .Net Core 2.0 и обновление для студии 15.3 выкатили. Теперь какая-то чахорда с .Net Framework 4.7, C# 7, .Net Standart, .Net Core. Пакеты лучше ставить через Manager а не через консоль, т.к. в нем можно выбрать конкретную версию того или иного пакета.

Comment: @Bulson, вы невнимательно прочитали. Требуемой версии нет совсем... ее не существует

Comment: Эта версия существует, у вас это сообщение говорит о том, что загруженная вами версия пакета не соответствует требуемой. Откройте менеджер пакетов, удалите установленный пакет, и снова устанавливайте, но укажите версию, которая требуется.

Comment: @Bulson, я же говорю вам, что ее не существует.